# Bounding roots of a parabola

Tags: inequality, roots, quadratics, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Given the quadratic equation
$$ax^2+bx+c=0,$$
I am trying to bound its roots. The solutions are 
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
but using the triangle inequality
$$|x_{1,2}|\leq\frac{|b|+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2|a|}=\frac{|b|+\sqrt{(b-2\sqrt{ac})(b+2\sqrt{ac})}}{2|a|}$$
and by AM-GM inequality we have
$$\frac{|b|+\frac{(|b|-2\sqrt{ac})+(|b|+2\sqrt{ac})}2}{2|a|}=\frac{|b|+|b|}{2|a|}=\left|\frac{b}{a}\right|.$$
Thus
$$|x_{1,2}|\leq \left|\frac{b}{a}\right|,$$
However, if I try this with $3x^2-x-19=0$, I have that one root is $2.68$, while $b/a=1/3$. Why is this wrong?

Comment: Bounding the roots when you have the exact values is a little illogical. To get a meaningful bound, you should specify what kind of approximation you expect.

Comment: @YvesDaoust it’s a more generalized problem for stability Of numerical schemes of pdes. A, b, c are complex valued and very long. They are functions of $dt$ and $dx$, thus by a bound you want to find a relationship between the 2.

Comment: That doesn't change my comment.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I was looking for an approximation that is less than one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is assuming that you're operating under the restriction that the coefficients and the roots are real. What you're doing is basically saying that:

$$\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \leq |b|$$

which is obviously false if $ac < 0$.

The error in the AM-GM application (which can only be applied for non-negative numbers) stems from assuming $\sqrt{ac}$ exists, which it doesn't when $ac < 0$, as is the case of your equation.

The bound is good however, for second degree equations with $\frac{b^2}{4} \geq ac \geq 0$.

Comment: What if $a,b$ and $c$ are complexed valued? Wouldn’t then $\sqrt{ac}$ when the argument is negative make sense?

Comment: @DMH16, How do you compare complex numbers? Or did you mean you want to bound the module of the roots? The points is if $\sqrt{ac}$ is a complex number, AM-GM is a no-no.